# How do I delete registrations and automatically recalculate the invoice total?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, invoice

An end user registered too many people for an event. The client removed participants but the invoice total is not automatically recalculated to reflect fewer participants. Is there a proper way to do this or how do I make the correction to the invoice?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible with the [Line Item Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor) extension.

Comment: First, thanks for tip about the Line Item Editor. It certainly solves part of the problem. However, it looks like the Invoice total does not update correctly, so this is a partial solution at best.  I'm still looking for a more complete fix.

Comment: If you believe that's a bug in the Line Item Editor extension, I recommend opening a bug report with the extension authors!

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'm reviewing with the client next week to determine if this is due to a bug or accounting procedure. I'll certainly report it as a bug once we are certain that's the case.